# Files management

Tags: java, android, json, file, android-studio

I have a ApplicationData.json file which includes some data used by my application.

The file is created before the app starts (manually) and it will never be deleted.
Sometimes, I need to override it's data by recreate the file with the updated data
.
In addition, I have more files which are generated on runtime.

I want all files to be reachable outside from my application manually.

1. In which path should I use while read & write to them?
2. Where should I locate my ApplicationData.json file before the app starts using Android Studio files explorer?

Comment: *Before the app starts.. how could you run the code, if app is not there..??

Comment: Comon.. I said that the file will be created manually..